# nginx clean url router/rewrites

Tags: linux, php, nginx, debian, php-fpm

im having difficulties with a relativity simple rewrite rules / router in nginx config.

All I want to do is, if requested dir or file 'host/my/request/path[/[index.php]]' does not exist, rewrite to 'host/my/request/path.php'

Current rewrite works for:

```
host
host/
host/my/request/path
```

But wont work for:

```
host/my/request/path/
```

Here is the rewrite part of the config:

```
    location / {
             try_files $uri/ $uri $uri.php;
    }
```

Error log will report:

```
Access forbidden by rule, request: "GET /my/request/path/ HTTP/1.0"
```

Hm, is there a better way to solve this or get rid of the trailing slash?

edit, rules more elaborative:

```
host[/] >  host/index.php
host/index[/] >  host/index.php
host/my/path[/] > if /path/index.php exists: host/my/path/index.php
else host/my/path.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557936/nginx-trailing-slash-rewrite-results-in-a-redirect-loop

I added

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;
```

before the rule in first post, seems to be working.